# Pip : Fatal error in launcher -because of wrong path

Tags: python, path, pip, fatal-error

I had python 32 bit installed so i uninstalled it and installed the 64 bit version.
I upgraded the path also but when i try using **pip** it is still using the previous path of the 32 bit python and pip

this is the exact error in cmd :

**Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\users\sagar annaji\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Sagar Annaji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts\pip.e
xe" install numpy'**

while i think with my new path the command should have been:

**'"C:\Users\Sagar Annaji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe"  "C:\Users\Sagar Annaji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\pip.exe" install numpy'**

python works fine but pip doesnt i included a pic of my path variables please help me resolve it.

[image: path variable]

Comment: How are you invoking `pip`?

Comment: `python -m pip install numpy` (might need to provide the full path to *Python*).

Comment: @C.Nivs i just used (pip install) in cmd

Comment: @CristiFati yes python -m pip install works but i want to be able to use just pip normally like before

Comment: It's important to use `python -m pip` because that ensures that `pip` is pointing to the correct python. The `pip` binary by itself might point to the wrong place

Comment: @C.Nivs oh didnt know that was the case, Thank you ver much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use python -m pip because that ensures that pip is pointing to the correct python. The pip binary by itself might point to the wrong place

thanks to user @C.Nivs

Comment: You can also fix the problem of the pip binary pointing to the wrong place.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63396570/pip-is-selecting-wrong-path